# Force a hyperlink to open in a new window using context.Response

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web page having links to some pdf files, e.g. http://www.someurl.com/somefolder/filename.pdf.

When a user clicks on these links, authentication kicks in, user logs in and the file can be downloaded. What I'm trying to achieve is that the downloads open in a new window.

I have a limited access/control to the code and can't put `target=_blank` attribute to href or add any javascript. The code that downloads after authentication is as below:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(context.Request.PhysicalPath);

FileStream MyFileStream;
long FileSize;

string strMapPath = context.Server.MapPath(filename);
MyFileStream = new FileStream(strMapPath, FileMode.Open);
FileSize = MyFileStream.Length;

//Allocate size for our buffer array
byte[] Buffer = new byte[(int)FileSize];
MyFileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)FileSize);
MyFileStream.Close();

//Do buffer cleanup
context.Response.Buffer = true;
context.Response.Clear();

//Add the appropriate headers
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
"attachement filename=" + filename);

//Add the right contenttype
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

//Stream it out via a Binary Write
context.Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
```

Can we possibly force `context.Response` to open in a new window?

Comment: Why don't Response.WriteFile?

Comment: Why can'nt you use target=_blank. Can you explain me the reason. I think, using HTTP Handler would solve your purpose.

Comment: can you please give me an example how would Response.WriteFile would open the link in new window? thanks

Comment: suryakiran - I m using httphandler to intercept the request and redirect the user to login page after the user is logged in, the code above to download file executes

Comment: Can you use a trick like this?

    `Response.Write("<script>window.open('+FilePath+','_blank');</script>");`
In this way you will add dynamic JS to your page opening in a _blank target as you wish without touching base code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening a new window is a client side action whereas `Context.Response` is a server side command. To open the new window you would need to do something on the client side.

If you can't change the original page source to run script or alter the HTML then what you want can't be done. You could on a request return a page that has script to open a new window but it wouldn't be the same. You'd either have to recreate the original page entirely except with the added script (and if you can do that I assume you could just change the original page) or you'd have a different page that opens up the popup.

The only good solution to this is to change the original page to add the popup script either with a `target="_blank"` or with script that adds an onclick handler to the link. Both of these you say you can't do.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but here's what I had done to achieve the OP was after.

First things first, it appears you were on the right track but I noticed that you had spelled *attachment* incorrectly And forgot to supply a ";" directly after the "attachment" Content-Disposition declaration.

This is the original code that I had used that displayed the same behavior that you have described!

**Change your Content-Disposition Declaration to this**

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + docName + ".pdf");
```

**Additional notes**

- If you specify the Content-Disposition as "Inline" it will output the
  file content in your current window.
- You need to change that disposition to "attachment" AND make sure
  your extension suffix is explicitly set to .pdf.